# Update text, without clearing icons in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, replace

I have a table that you can select rows and edit fields with from a dialog. These table rows typically have an icon for drag and drop capability, as well as an icon for attachments. The issue is that when you edit the text from the dialog, the icons clear regardless of whether I use .html() or .text(). I believe using a form of .content() is viable, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I've tried to avoid clearing the images with .not() with no luck. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/11/

```
$( ".saveBtn" ).click(function() {
    properties.eq(0).html($("#name").val()); 
    properties.eq(1).html($("#perm").val());
});
```

Comment: Wrap the text in a `<span>`, select that, then update its contents?

Comment: I don't understand what your demo is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what you have you can just replace the text like this:

```
$(".saveBtn").click(function () {
    properties.get(0).firstChild.nextSibling.nodeValue = $("#name").val();
    properties.eq(1).text($("#perm").val());
    $(".prop").dialog("close");
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMBqG/)**

But it would be better to wrap your text in another element, and set the value for it for better operation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .content() like this

```
$( ".saveBtn" ).click(function() {
    properties.eq(0).contents()[1].textContent=$("#name").val(); 
    properties.eq(1).html($("#perm").val());
    $( ".prop" ).dialog( "close" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/19/
Edit
if you need the code to work on IE lower than 9 you can do this

```
$( ".saveBtn" ).click(function() {
    properties.eq(0).contents().eq(1).wrap("<span></span>").parent().html($("#name").val()); 
    properties.eq(1).html($("#perm").val());
    $( ".prop" ).dialog( "close" );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BWCBX/20/

Comment: it will not work on IE 8,7,6 [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent)